# Create jQuery tabs with dropdown rather than links

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create tabbed content controlled by a dropdown menu. I'm using the 'change' event, but for some reason it's not happening. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

HTML:

```
<select class="tabs" >
    <option class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab 1</option>
    <option class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab 2</option>
    <option class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab 3</option>
    <option class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab 4</option>
</select>

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
    Tab one content.
</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    Tab two content.
</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    Tab three content.
</div>
<div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
    Tab four content.
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('select.tabs option').change(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('select.tabs option').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    })
```

And here's a jsfidde: [http://jsfiddle.net/85V3D/](http://jsfiddle.net/85V3D/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First load jQuery (in fiddle you have selected Pure Js in frameworks option)
2. `$('select.tabs option')` should be 
   `$('select.tabs')`
3. `this` in `change` function refers to the `select` element (not to the selected option element) and hence `var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');` return `undefined`

To get selected `option` element (not the selected value) use

```
$('select.tabs').change(function () {
    var option = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    alert($(option).attr('data-tab'));
})
```

Here is the [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/85V3D/3/)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the fiddle. The 'current' class now disappears when a change is made, but it is not then added to the new option and div. It's adding 'current' class to select (not an option) only.